Forest Plot or Plotting OddsRatio in a Table
I am trying to report the prevalence's and plot the Odds Ratio in a descriptive table something similar to this Post by R for Health Data Science Book. This creates a forest plot. Since I have other values so I cant use finalfit package but I tried to produce the same table by following the Answer-2 of this Question. I already made the descriptive Table and plotted the odds ratio with dummy values but some of the columns are overlapping, for instance Non-MM and MM. Secondly, the group Sex and its subgroup Male is not showing. It might be the formatting issue but I couldn't find it. You can find the snap with highlighted areas and its code, as they mentioned in the code. Thanks 
mydf <- data.frame(
    SubgroupH = c('Sex', NA, NA, 'Age-Group', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'SIMD', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    Subgroup = c(
        NA, 'Male', 'Female', NA, '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55',
        '56-65', '66-75', '76-85', '86+', NA, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
    ),
    total_cohort = c(NA,18494,3874,NA,23,54,67,43,65,76,23,122,NA,23,43,54,65,34),
    non_mm = c(NA,18494,3874,NA,23,54,67,43,65,76,23,122,NA,23,43,54,65,34),
    mm = c(NA,18494,3874,NA,64,24,37,43,85,76,32,22,NA,82,54,30,87,20),
    cmm = c(NA,18494,3874,NA,44,54,67,43,65,76,23,122,NA,23,43,54,65,34),
    ODDs_Ratio = c(NA,0.594,0.5,NA,'-',0.74,0.73,0.63,0.75,0.79,0.43,0.42,NA,'-',0.60,0.64,0.69,0.44),
    CI_lower = c(NA,0.394,0.3,NA,'-',0.54,0.67,0.43,0.65,0.76,0.23,0.122,NA,'-',0.43,0.54,0.65,0.34),
    CI_upper = c(NA,0.69,0.7,NA,'-',0.94,0.97,0.83,0.95,0.99,0.63,0.52,NA,'-',0.83,0.94,0.95,0.74),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Updated plot code
rowseq <- seq(nrow(mydf), 1)
par(mai=c(0.5, 0, 0, 0))
plot(mydf$ODDs_Ratio, rowseq, pch=15,
    xlim=c(-10, 12), ylim=c(0, 16),
    xlab='', ylab='', yaxt='n', xaxt='n',
    bty='n')
axis(1, seq(-2, 2, by=.4), cex.axis=.5)

segments(1, -1, 1, 15.25, lty=3)
segments(mydf$mm, rowseq, mydf$cmm, rowseq)

#mtext('Off-Pump\nCABG Better', 1, line=2.5, at=0, cex=.5, font=2)
#mtext('On-Pump\nCABG Better', 1.5, line=2.5, at=2, cex=.5, font=2)

text(-8, 16.5, "Subgroup", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t1h <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$SubgroupH), mydf$SubgroupH, '')
text(-8, rowseq, t1h, cex=.75, pos=4, font=3)
t1 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Subgroup), mydf$Subgroup, '')
text(-7.5, rowseq, t1, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(-5, 16.5, "Total Cohort", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t2 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$total_cohort), format(mydf$total_cohort, big.mark=","), '')
text(-3, rowseq, t2, cex=.75, pos=2)

text(7.5, 16.5, "NO-MM", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t3 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$non_mm), mydf$non_mm, '')
text(7.5, rowseq, t3, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(7.5, 16.5, "MM", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t4 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$mm), mydf$mm, '')
text(7.5, rowseq, t4, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(10, 16.5, "CMM", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t5 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$cmm), mydf$cmm, '')
text(10, rowseq, t5, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(-1, 16.5, "ODDs_Ratio", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t6 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$ODDs_Ratio), with(mydf, paste(ODDs_Ratio, ' (', CI_lower, '-', CI_upper, ')', sep='')), '')
text(3, rowseq, t6, cex=.75, pos=4)


You are overplotting MM and NO-MM -- they both get the same position via text(7.5, 16, ...). You fix your y-axis range to 0-16 in the plot call but you have 18 rows of data in rowseq. It's not clear exactly what you do want the plot to look like but these are what's causing the issues you name.

The issue is simply one of moving the columns around a bit, until you get it how you want. A bit of trial and error ensues.
Here's the original plot:

And here is the updated one:

And this is the code I used to create it:
rowseq <- seq(nrow(mydf), 1)
par(mai=c(0.5, 0, 0, 0))
plot(mydf$ODDs_Ratio, rowseq, pch=15,
     xlim=c(-10, 12), ylim=c(0, nrow(mydf) + 2),
     xlab='', ylab='', yaxt='n', xaxt='n',
     bty='n')
axis(1, seq(-2, 2, by=.4), cex.axis=.5)

segments(1, -1, 1, nrow(mydf) + 1, lty=3)
segments(mydf$mm, rowseq, mydf$cmm, rowseq)

text(-8, nrow(mydf) + 1, "Subgroup", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t1h <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$SubgroupH), mydf$SubgroupH, '')
text(-8, rowseq, t1h, cex=.75, pos=4, font=3)
t1 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Subgroup), mydf$Subgroup, '')
text(-7.5, rowseq, t1, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(-5, nrow(mydf) + 1, "Total Cohort", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t2 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$total_cohort), format(mydf$total_cohort, big.mark=","), '')
text(-3, rowseq, t2, cex=.75, pos=2)

text(6, nrow(mydf) + 1, "NO-MM", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t3 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$non_mm), mydf$non_mm, '')
text(6, rowseq, t3, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(8.5, nrow(mydf) + 1, "MM", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t4 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$mm), mydf$mm, '')
text(8.5, rowseq, t4, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(11, nrow(mydf) + 1, "CMM", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t5 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$cmm), mydf$cmm, '')
text(11, rowseq, t5, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(-2, nrow(mydf) + 1, "ODDs_Ratio", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t6 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$ODDs_Ratio), with(mydf, paste(ODDs_Ratio, ' (', CI_lower, '-', CI_upper, ')', sep='')), '')
text(2, rowseq, t6, cex=.75, pos=4)

